# Strategy for passing redux routing link callbacks to leaf components?

Tags: router, redux

There are various redux routing libs (redux-router, redux-simple-router, etc.) and their common motivation is to keep router state in the single redux state tree. Therefore, if we want to change the route state we need to dispatch an action. But...one of the "rules" of redux is that dumb components should not know about redux, so, to dispatch a route change in some deeply nested component one has to pass a "dispatch route change" callback from a container all the way down to the leaf component. Any ideas on a clean strategy on handling this?

Answer (score 1):

A friend pointed out http://rackt.org/redux/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html Thanks Joe!